# Magento customer registration not saving selected state/region

Tags: javascript

So for some reason my Magento install (1.5) stopped saving new customers state/region name, both inside admin and outside.

Magento's `registration form` has a `dropdown select`, with a name of `"region_id"` and a hidden text field named `"region"`. I guess that some javascript is supposed to get the selected name and set the "region" field, but that doesn't work.

What I did was create a jQuery line that, on form submit, gets the region name and sets the "region" field to it. That works, somewhat. There are still customers who are registering without a region name, only the id.

Anyone ever had something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Magento should have some JS (using Prototype) to handle that functionality.  It sounds like that functionality no longer works.

Did the problem start around the same time you added jQuery to the site?  If so, the issue is likely being caused by a JavaScript variable conflict.

Both Protoype and jQuery use the `$` variable for selecting elements.  In Prototype, `$` is a shortcut for `document.getElementById`.  The code to get an input element with the id `region` would look like this : `var field = $('region');`  However, if `$` refers to the jQuery library, this code would instead try to locate a `<region>` element, just like `$('body')` would match the `<body>` tag.

The solution to this is preventing jQuery from causing the conflict.  Immediately after jQuery is included on the page, execute this JS: `jQuery.noConflict()`.  This causes jQuery to give the `$` variable back to Prototype, thus resolving the conflict and fixing the standard Magento JS.

Any custom code expecting `$` to refer to jQuery will now break.  There are two possible solutions:

- Rename `$` to `jQuery` in all your code (messy, time-consuming)
- Wrap it in a closure, essentially creating an alias of `$ = jQuery` only for the code within that closure.

Here's what the closure looks like:

```
// Outside of here, $ might refer to Prototype or jQuery - we simply don't know
(function($){
    // Your code goes here.  Any reference to $ inside here will always be for jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

Here's a quick example:

**Before:**

```
// $ refers to the Prototype function
$('#header ul').hide();
```

**After:**

```
(function($){
    // $ now refers to jQuery
    $('#header ul').hide();
})(jQuery);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Might be the reason, even though I think I have called the $.noConflict();